# Preserving the values that the pointers stored in STL container point to (unordered_map)

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

I have a data structure as following

```
struct routing
{
    int color;       //white = -1, gray = 0, black = 1
    unsigned int d;      //distance
    unsigned int pi;     //previous node id

    routing() : color (-1), d (UINT_MAX), pi (UINT_MAX ) {}
};

struct attraction //each node in graph is called an attraction
{
    unsigned int id;                           //id of node
    std::string name;                          //name
    unsigned int priority;                     //priority
    std::unordered_map<int, int> nodeMap;      //destination node id, distance
    routing r;                                 //routing information

    attraction() : id (0) , name(""), priority(0) {}
};
```

Now, I have to run the Dijkstra algorithm to find the shortest distance between different nodes (called attractions). I have implemented it and it's working just fine. Except that it's slow(er than I need).
I have an STL container which stores information about the nodes. I use this to perform the routing.  It is given below:

```
//I use unordered_map for fast access of elements.
typedef std::unordered_map<unsigned int, attraction*> attractionList;
attractionList attrList;
```

What I'm trying to do is once I calculate all the paths/costs of all the vertices from a certain node and store it in the **attractionList** container, I want to reuse this information, so that subsequent routing calls from that certain source node will be faster. For this I want to save the state of my **attrList** container, so I can quickly reuse the information stored. What I'm trying is something like this:

```
//make another container whose first element is a unique source id, second element is the attractionList 
std::unordered_map<unsigned int, attractionList> stateMap; (containig routing information)

attractionList* newList = new attractionList(); //make a new object to store old state
newList = &attrList;     //copy values from old state

//insert in another container so that each unique source id has all routing information stored
stateMap.insert(std::pair<unsigned int, attractionList> (from, *newList));
```

Well, the problem with this is obvious. When the pointers stored in the **attrList** change all the copies made from it are invalid. How do I store them permanently? How is the copying being done in this container? If necessary how do I overload the assignment operator? Is this even possible? I can make slight changes to my data structure and containers but not much.

Sorry for the long post. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem is that you blindly use `new` without any rhyme or reason. `newList = &attrList;` is an instant memory leak.

Comment: `newList = &attrList;     //copy values from old state` — I don't think it means what you think it means.

Comment: @n.m. I'm bit of a novice (a sleep deprived one). So in this case my newList will just point to the old one, right? But still, I can't get it right, even if I declare newList on the stack.

Comment: "I can't get it right" contains about one bit of information, which is not enough to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify. I need to reset the routing information in every node (attraction*) stored in attrList before I can compute the distance from a new source node. But as I said I need to preserve the old routing information. I tried to declare a new list on stack by `attractionList newList = attrList;` as @Steve Jessop suggested, and add it to the stateMap. But when I reset the data in attrList the newly 'stored' list's data also becomes NUll/reset. attrList is declared in a class as a private member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
attractionList* newList = new attractionList(); //make a new object to store old state
newList = &attrList;     //copy values from old state
```

> Well, the problem with this is obvious. When the pointers stored in
>   the attrList change all the copies made from it are invalid.

You didn't make a copy. You allocated a new, empty list on the heap, then you discarded your pointer to it and stored a pointer to the existing list.

I think you mean:

```
attractionList newList = attrList;
```

but I haven't reviewed the rest of your code, so that might not be a complete fix.

Regarding your comment:

If you need to copy the attractions as well, then you'll need somewhere to store them. Since you don't say how you're storing the originals I can't tell you where to store the copies, but the rest of the code will be something like this:

```
attractionList newList;
for (attractionList::iterator it = attrList.begin(); it != attrList.end(); ++it) {
    attraction *newNode = /* copy of *(it->second) */;
    newList.insert(make_pair(it->first, newNode));
}
```

Comment: Same problem persists. attrList contains pointers to nodes. I need to reset the data of all nodes each time I calculate path for a new source. But when I do it overwrites the old one. Basically now I'm doing this  
    `auto it = stateMap.find(source);`  
    `if (it == stateMap.end())`  
    `{`
      `resetNodes();`
      `bool d=dijkstra(attrList.at(from),attrList.at(to));`   
      `attractionList newList = attrList;`
      `stateMap.insert(std::pair<unsigned int, attractionList(from, newList));`
      `return d;`
    `}`